Problem with Jira subtask template. Inherit not working on Summary
So I have an old Jira Version (v7.13.5) and I'm trying to get the Task Summary as part of the Subtask Summary.
What I've done is this:
Rack: "@inherit" / description:"Procedura di Rack degli apparati" / assignee:jiradatacenter / cfield:"Customer:@inherit" / duedate:"@inherit" / priority: "@inherit" / labels: "Datacenter"

And I've also tried with this:
Rack: @inherit / description:"Procedura di Rack degli apparati" / assignee:jiradatacenter / cfield:"Customer:@inherit" / duedate:"@inherit" / priority: "@inherit" / labels: "Datacenter"

None of them is working, but the other @inherit information are gathering all the data that I've required. Can it be that the version of Jira is not supporting this feature?

Resolved: insted of @inherit I've used @{summary}
